# jQuery .on with multiple events, multiple handlers and applying to new elements

Tags: jquery, events, handler

I have a list that has items dynamically removed/added.

```
$('#myul').on('mouseenter', 'li', function() {
    //do something
});
```

but I want multiple events, each handled differently

```
$('#myul').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        //do something
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        //do something else
    }
});
```

I can't target $('.myul li') because that won't affect new list items. I tried sticking 'li', before function() but jQuery didn't like that. I also tried .hover but it had the same problem (doesn't apply to new list items.)

Is there any way to do this without having a different function for each event+handler?

Comment: Check out [Direct and Delegated Events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) in the documentation.

Comment: I did! My first example is the exact same as their first example except with different selectors/event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put it after the event handler:

```
$('#myul').on({
  mouseenter:function(){...},
  mouseleave:function(){...}
} ,'li');
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks so much :D Do you know if there's a page in the API with this? I tried before the opening curly bracket in .on but I didn't think to try before the closing one

Comment: Idk if it's in the docs... just knowing the argument order:  `on([events], [selectors], [handlers])` and then knowing that you can "add in" handlers to the events by using an object... so selectors would still go after.